# focus() not working in this getUi().showSidebar html in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script

I'm opening a sidebar containing a form in Google Sheets using a custom Menubar function.

I want the `<textarea>` to be focused whenever sidebar opens (so that cursor is in it, and any typing adds to it right away). But using `focus()` is not working. (Applying style to it *is* working, as per the next line.)

How can I accomplish that please? Thank you very much for your help.

**NOTE:** It is not working in Chrome (Win 10), but it does in Firefox.

```
function abc() {
    var html = 
    '<form id="form">' + 
    '<textarea id="title"> </textarea> '+ 
    '</form> <button>Submit</button> '+
    '<script>'+
    ' document.getElementById("title").focus(); '+ // << NOT WORKING 
    ' document.getElementById("title").style.outline ="solid 2px red"' +  // << WORKING
    ' </script>'+
    '';

  var a = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html)
  .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
  .setTitle('MY-FORM')
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(a); 
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('My Functions')
  .addItem('Start', 'abc')
  .addSeparator()
  .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: In my case, your code does focus on the textarea when I open the Sidebar. Does the solution provided by Cooper solve your issue?

Comment: @Jescanellas Unfortunately Cooper's solution is still not working for me in Chrome (Win 10) and I have edited my question to reflect that. Thanks.

Comment: That's weird, have you tried in incognito mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait for the Page to load.

Try this:

```
function abc() {
  var html ='<form><input type="text" id="title" name="title" /><br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);"/></form>';
  html+='<script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("title").focus();document.getElementById("title").style.outline="solid 2px red";}</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui); 
}

function processForm(obj) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sh.getRange('A1').setValue(obj.title);
}
```

You can also use a textarea as well:

```
function abc() {
  var html ='<form><textarea rows="1" cols="15" id="title" name="title"></textarea><br /><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="google.script.run.processForm(this.parentNode);"/></form>';
  html+='<script>window.onload=function(){document.getElementById("title").focus();document.getElementById("title").style.outline="solid 2px red";}</script>';
  var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(ui); 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is still not working for me in Chrome (Win 10). I should note that the code even without `window.onload` works in Firefox. I am now editing my question to reflect that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the Boolean attribute [autofocus](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea):

```
'<textarea id="title" autofocus> </textarea> '
```

Comment: I ran in chrome V8 last night